# Is it possible to write a functor Interface for .NET?

Tags: .net, functional-programming

Functional languages often have [Functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) types/interfaces.

In .NET a Functor interface would be an Interface implementable by generic types (`T<A>`) that has a function called fmap that takes a function from the container type (`A`) to a different type (`B`) and returns an object with container type B.

For example a type `List<A>` would have a method List.fmap. The signature would be something like:

```
public List<B> fmap<B>(Func<A,B>);
```

Is it possible to create such an interface? Is it possible to do something similar? Are there any packages that provide an Interface like this and provide extension methods for obvious classes (`List<T>`, `Dictionary<A,B>`, `Set<A>`, etc.) ?

**Update**:

I know that IEnumerable objects almost do this. The key difference is that IEnumerable.Select returns an IEnumerable not the type of the implementer. For example, List.Select(A => B) returns IEnumerable not List. This shows why you can not implement IMappable in the obvious way for .NET, but is there a hack or extra type information you could use to effectively implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, based on the comment, I *suspect* the answer's no - you'd need higher-order generic types. You'd want something like:

```
// Not real syntax!
interface IFunctor<TFunctor<?>, TValue>
    where TFunctor<X> : IFunctor<TFunctor<X>, TValue>
{
    TFunctor<TProjection> Project<TProjection>(Func<TValue, TProjection> func);
}
```

The problem is trying to express the idea that the implementation of the interface must *also* be generic in a particular way, and allow that generic relationship to be used in the rest of the interface. That's not part of .NET generics, I'm afraid.

Joe Duffy has written about [wishing for higher-order types](http://joeduffyblog.com/2008/11/04/longing-for-higherkinded-c/) before now - unfortunately I can't tell whether or not that article is relevant, as I can't get to it at the moment. (His blog server is somewhat temporamently, but the content is great :)

---

It's not entirely clear, but it's possible you're just talking about [LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx), basically. For example:

```
var kids = people.Where(x => x.Age < 18) // Filtering
                 .Select(x => x.Name)    // Projection
                 .ToList();
```

You could write a more general purpose interface, e.g.

```
public interface IFunctor<T>
{
    IFunctor<TOther> Foo<TOther>(Func<T, TOther> selector);
}
```

... but there's no such interface actually implemented by `List<T>` etc. LINQ to Objects works via extension methods instead.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I know that IEnumerable objects *almost* do this. The key difference is that IEnumerable<T>.Select returns an IEnumerable<B> not the type of the implementer<B>. For example, List<A>.Select(A => B) returns IEnumerable<B> not List<B>. This clarifies for me why you can not implement IMappable in the obvious way for .NET, but I wonder if there is some kind of a hack or extra type information you could use to effectively implement. Question updated to reflect this, thanks :)

Comment: @John: Are you interested in the academic sense? It's not like you'll be able to make `List<T>` implement an interface that it doesn't already implement... but if you're interested in how it *could* work, that might be a different matter.

Comment: @John: I've edited my answer - see if that's more useful to you.

Comment: I believe you can implement interfaces for existing classes using extension methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: @John: You can't actually implement interfaces. You can make it appear that you're adding methods, but you can't make a type actually implement an interface - if you do `if (foo is IBar)` it will still return false. Extension methods are just C# syntactic sugar for calling static methods.

Comment: The Joe Duffy link doesn't work but I found the post here instead: http://joeduffyblog.com/2008/11/04/longing-for-higherkinded-c/

Answer (score 3):

The difficulty of giving a type to `fmap` is that it is parameterized by a higher-kinded type variable, the container type. So beyond being a simple polymorphic function, like say, `map` on lists:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
```

`fmap` generalizes this to work on any container, as well as any element type:

```
fmap :: Functor (f :: * -> *) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

The problem in C# is that `f` is a higher-kinded type variable (it is a type function). Since C# doesn't support higher kinds, you'll be out of luck writing this directly,  think.